# ¿Cómo hacer una busqueda recursiva en una pagina?

Tags: python, scraping, scrapy

Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda recursiva en una página web con Scrapy. He modificado el valor en el fichero de `settings.py` de `DEPTH_LIMIT  = 4` y mi código queda de la siguiente manera:

```py
class HreflocalizeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'hrefLocalize'
    allowed_domains = [URL]
    start_urls = ('URL_DE_BUSQUEDA',)
    rules = Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse', follow=True)
    settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = 4 # Puse esto para forzar el cambio
    settings.overrides['DEPTH_PRIORITY'] = 4

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        lines = hxs.xpath('//@href').extract()
        linkPattern = re.compile(r'^(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:[\w\.\-\+]+:{0,1}[\w\.\-\+]*@)?(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$')
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
            if linkPattern.match(line):
                yield Request(line, self.parse)
```

Pero aún así con todo esto, el programa siempre me dice que

```
'request_depth_max': 1
```

He visto que importa el *middleware* para hacer la búsqueda en profundidad, pero aún así, no hace dicha búsqueda.

¿Alguien me podría echar una mano y decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Por defecto `DEPTH_LIMIT`es `0` esto quiere decir que no tiene límite.

La variable que tu mencionas `request_depth_max` es del resultado de lo que hizo el código no la configuración.

En tu código `spider` no hace ninguna consulta a otras páginas, solo busca información de las páginas superiores, es por eso que el `request_depth_max` es siempre 1

Si haces que envíe consultas a otras páginas entonces `request_depth_max` será mayor a 1